# on select color change background color

Tags: jquery, select, colors, background

I have the bootstrap grid with the button to prompt bootstrap modal to select the color.

I'm trying to select the color using colorsector.js under jquery and it works great when you see the list of color.

Also, it works great when selected color and show and shows color code number in text field area.

My best next step is that after selected color and show in text area then press change button, is suppose to change the background color in grid box of what we selected color but is not working. any idea what did I miss! please see in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Alidad3250/xmrxbL9f/563/)

I use jquery code like this

```
$('#applyChanges').on('click', function () {

  $('#colbg').val(column.css('background-color'));
    // css class
    $('#colcss').val(column.attr('class'));

    })
```

Comment: check the console first, the jsfiddle you created has error logs in the console.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by console first in Jsfiddle, i do not have problem with error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your js event to this. It changes the background color of #colcss. Is that what you wanted?

```
$('#applyChanges').on('click', function () {
    var chosenColor = $('#colbg').val();
    $('#colcss').css({ backgroundColor: chosenColor });
})
```

```js
$('#applyChanges').on('click', function () {
  if ($('#tabs-837046 li').eq(0).hasClass('active')) {
    $('.container-fluid > .row > div').eq(0).css({ backgroundColor: $('#colbg').val() });
  }
  if ($('#tabs-837046 li').eq(1).hasClass('active')) {
    $('.container-fluid > .row > div').eq(1).css({ backgroundColor: $('#rowbg').val() });
  }  
})
```

```css
.modal-content.ui-resizable {
  
}
/* colorselector dropdown */
.dropdown-colorselector>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 80%;
  left: -7px;
  padding: 4px;
  min-width: 130px;
  max-width: 130px;
}

/*
.dropdown-colorselector>.dropdown-menu.pull-right {
  right: -7px;
  left: auto;
}
*/
.dropdown-colorselector>.dropdown-menu>li {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 2px;
}

.dropdown-colorselector>.dropdown-menu>li>.color-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.1s;
  transition: all ease 0.1s;
}

.dropdown-colorselector>.dropdown-menu>li>.color-btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  filter: alpha(opacity = 80);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.08);
  transform: scale(1.08);
}

.dropdown-colorselector>.dropdown-menu>li>.color-btn.selected:after {
  content: "\e013";
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.btn-colorselector {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 0;
}

.dropdown-menu.dropdown-caret:before {
  border-bottom: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  left: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -7px;
}

.dropdown-menu.dropdown-caret:after {
  border-bottom: 6px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -6px;
}
#colcss {
  height: 500px;
}

/*
.dropdown-menu.pull-right.dropdown-caret:before {
  left: auto;
  right: 9px;
}

.dropdown-menu.pull-right.dropdown-caret:after {
  left: auto;
  right: 10px;
}
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-colorselector@0.1.0/dist/bootstrap-colorselector.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid" data-count=0>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Cell color
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    Row color
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div id="colcss"

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="tabbable" id="tabs-837046">
            
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                                            
                                <li role="presentation"><a href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#CellSettings"
                                 aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Cell settings</a>
                                </li>
                                
                                <li role="presentation"><a href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#RowSettings"
                                 aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Row settings</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                
                
                
    <div class="tab-content">
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="CellSettings">
    
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="CellSettings">
                                    <div class="panel panel-body">
                                        
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Background color :</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="colbg">
                                                    <select id="colorselectorbg" style="display: none;">
                                                        <option value="1" data-value="1" data-color="#A0522D">sienna</option>
                                                        <option value="2" data-value="2" data-color="#CD5C5C">indianred</option>
                                                        <option value="3" data-value="3" data-color="#FF4500">orangered</option>
                                                        <option value="4" data-value="4" data-color="#008B8B">darkcyan</option>
                                                        <option value="5" data-value="5" data-color="#B8860B">darkgoldenrod</option>
                                                        <option value="6" data-value="6" data-color="#32CD32">limegreen</option>
                                                        <option value="7" data-value="7" data-color="#FFD700">gold</option>
                                                        <option value="8" data-value="8" data-color="#48D1CC">mediumturquoise</option>
                                                        <option value="9" data-value="9" data-color="#87CEEB">skyblue</option>
                                                        <option value="10" data-value="10" data-color="#FF69B4">hotpink</option>
                                                       
                                                        <option value="23" data-value="23" data-color="#ffffff">bianco</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-colorselector"><a data-toggle="dropdown" 
                                                    class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#">
                                                    <span class="btn-colorselector" style="background-color: rgb(160, 82, 45);"></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                    
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-caret">
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn selected" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#A0522D" data-value="1" title="sienna" 
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(160, 82, 45);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#CD5C5C" data-value="2" title="indianred"
                                                                  style="background-color: rgb(205, 92, 92);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#" 
                                                                data-color="#FF4500" data-value="3" title="orangered"
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(255, 69, 0);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#" 
                                                                data-color="#008B8B" data-value="4" title="darkcyan"
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(0, 139, 139);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#B8860B" data-value="5" title="darkgoldenrod" 
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(184, 134, 11);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#32CD32" data-value="6" title="limegreen" 
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(50, 205, 50);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#" 
                                                                data-color="#FFD700" data-value="7" title="gold"
                                                                style="background-color: rgb(255, 215, 0);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#" 
                                                                data-color="#48D1CC" data-value="8" title="mediumturquoise" 
                                                                style="background-color: rgb(72, 209, 204);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#" 
                                                                data-color="#87CEEB" data-value="9" title="skyblue"
                                                                style="background-color: rgb(135, 206, 235);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#" 
                                                                data-color="#FF69B4" data-value="10" title="hotpink"
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(255, 105, 180);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                           
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#ffffff" data-value="23" title="bianco" 
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                        </ul>
                                                        
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                                        $('#colorselectorbg').colorselector({
                                                            callback: function(value, color, title) {
                                                                $("#colbg").val(color);
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    </script>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <!-- <div class="form-group"> <label>Css class :</label>
                                                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="colcss" /> </div> --></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
      
     </div>
                     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="RowSettings">
      <div class="panel panel-body">
                                        
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label>Background color :</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="rowbg">
                                                    <select id="colorselectorrowbg" style="display: none;">
                                                        <option value="1" data-value="1" data-color="#A0522D">sienna</option>
                                                        <option value="2" data-value="2" data-color="#CD5C5C">indianred</option>
                                                        <option value="3" data-value="3" data-color="#FF4500">orangered</option>
                                                        <option value="4" data-value="4" data-color="#008B8B">darkcyan</option>
                                                        <option value="5" data-value="5" data-color="#B8860B">darkgoldenrod</option>
                                                        <option value="6" data-value="6" data-color="#32CD32">limegreen</option>
                                                        <option value="7" data-value="7" data-color="#FFD700">gold</option>
                                                        <option value="8" data-value="8" data-color="#48D1CC">mediumturquoise</option>
                                                        <option value="9" data-value="9" data-color="#87CEEB">skyblue</option>
                                                        <option value="10" data-value="10" data-color="#FF69B4">hotpink</option>
                                                        <option value="11" data-value="11" data-color="#87CEFA">lightskyblue</option>
                                                       
                                                        <option value="23" data-value="23" data-color="#ffffff">bianco</option>
                                                    </select>
                                                    <div class="dropdown dropdown-colorselector"><a data-toggle="dropdown"
                                                     class="dropdown-toggle" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#">
                                                     <span class="btn-colorselector" style="background-color: rgb(160, 82, 45);"></span></a>
                                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-caret">
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn selected" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#A0522D" data-value="1" title="sienna"
                                                                  style="background-color: rgb(160, 82, 45);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#CD5C5C" data-value="2" title="indianred" 
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(205, 92, 92);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#FF4500" data-value="3" title="orangered"
                                                                  style="background-color: rgb(255, 69, 0);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#" 
                                                                data-color="#008B8B" data-value="4" title="darkcyan"
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(0, 139, 139);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#B8860B" data-value="5" title="darkgoldenrod"
                                                                  style="background-color: rgb(184, 134, 11);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#32CD32" data-value="6" title="limegreen"
                                                                  style="background-color: rgb(50, 205, 50);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#FFD700" data-value="7" title="gold" 
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(255, 215, 0);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                 data-color="#48D1CC" data-value="8" title="mediumturquoise"
                                                                  style="background-color: rgb(72, 209, 204);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#" 
                                                                data-color="#87CEEB" data-value="9" title="skyblue"
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(135, 206, 235);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#" 
                                                                data-color="#FF69B4" data-value="10" title="hotpink" 
                                                                style="background-color: rgb(255, 105, 180);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#" 
                                                                data-color="#87CEFA" data-value="11" title="lightskyblue"
                                                                 style="background-color: rgb(135, 206, 250);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                           
                                                            
                                                            <li>
                                                                <a class="color-btn" href="http://www.ugamy.com/demo/#"
                                                                data-color="#ffffff" data-value="23" title="bianco" 
                                                                style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></a>
                                                            </li>
                                                            
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                                        $('#colorselectorrowbg').colorselector({
                                                            callback: function(value, color, title) {
                                                                $("#rowbg").val(color);
                                                            }
                                                        });
                                                    </script>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                      
                                        </div>
                                       
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="applyChanges"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;Apply changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Edited. It updates the cell and row separately and changes the button backgrounds.